# How to grep for text in man pages?

Tags: linux, grep, osx

I find it useful to grep for text, e.g. specific options, in man pages from the command line.

However, `grep` doesn't work as expected, when operating on man pages, as can be seen below, where pattern `"-f"` only matches `"-"` and pattern `"--file"` matches nothing (`alias grep='grep --color=always'`):

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ alias grep
alias grep='grep --color=always'
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ man grep | grep -e "-f"
          [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color[=when]]
     -F, --fixed-strings
     -f file, --file=file
     -h, --no-filename
             --binary-file=without-match option.
     -L, --files-without-match
     -l, --files-with-matches
     --binary-files=value
     and the behaviour of the -f flag when used with an empty pattern file is
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ man grep | grep -e "--file"
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ echo "--file" | grep -e "--file"
--file
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ ▒
```

In contrast, matching piped text from `echo` works as expected, so has this something to do with "invisible" formatting of man pages? Is it possible to reliable grep text in man pages?

Note: I know `man -k` and `man -K`, but these don't exactly solve what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: `less` is the default pager for `man` on most systems and it allows you to search for regexps in documents, why do you have to use grep for this?

Comment: @oguzismail - I find it convenient. How do I see the default pager?

Comment: Well just open a man page and type `/--file` and hit enter, if it works, then it's `less` :D

Comment: parsing man pages isn't easy... https://explainshell.com/ might suit your case.. if you wish cli solution, here's a script that I tried https://github.com/learnbyexample/command_help (works most of the time,  but has known issues)

Comment: @Sundeep - is the reason that manpages are formatted using special "invisible" characters?

Comment: Is `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` defined in your environment?

Comment: The typical reasons for problems grepping manpages is that hyphens aren’t hyphens but minus symbols (‘‑’ rather than ‘-’). This has largely been fixed on current Linux distributions but I suspect it could still be a problem on macOS. There can also be issues with escape sequences used for formatting, but usually not when piping. What does `man grep | grep -e -file | od -t x1 -t a` output?

Comment: I wonder if man is producing overstrikes, so that grep is highlighting `-f` within `-\b-f\bf`. That `\bf` would overwrite the red `f`.

Comment: Am I understanding this right, you want to open `man` and skip right to a flag? If yes, this might help you: `fman () { man "$1" | less +/\ "$2" }` Run it like this: `fman grep -f`

Comment: @StephenKitt - aren't minus and hyphen the same character?

Comment: @Shuzheng not in roff, see [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2018-05/msg00069.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION 1 :  use a specific conf file for man

a configuration file `.man.raw.conf`

```
NROFF /usr/bin/groff -mandoc -Tlatin1 -P-u -P-b
```

a example of use of `man`

```
MyMAC:tmp e444$$ man  -C .man.raw.conf grep | grep -e --file
     -f file, --file=file
     -L, --files-without-match
     -l, --files-with-matches
```

SOLUTION 2 : use `colcrt -`

```
MyMAC:tmp e444$  man grep | colcrt -  | grep -e --file
     -f file, --file=file
     -L, --files-without-match
     -l, --files-with-matches
```

ps 1: without `-`  colcrt add more garbage

ps 2: this question and answer does not make sense on linux , because not the same behavior .

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Do you know how bold text are handled? I mean, `man` shows some text in bold - what happens to such bold text, when it is piped `man grep | ...`? I understand that `colcrt` removes underlining, which was present in `--file`, but what about bold text?

Comment: did you test the command line ?

Comment: Yes, I did :) It works great.

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** use grep on man pages. Man pages are encoded (not in plain English) the contents will not match the sentence you want to search for.

Assuming the program `man` is using `less` to show *man pages* there is a way to search with the help of `less`. Keep reading.

To confirm that your man pages are being presented by `less`, type `man grep` (or some other command), press *enter* and while viewing the man page, press only the key *h*. If it is less, the title of the *help* page presented is titled: **SUMMARY OF LESS COMMANDS**. Once you have confirmed that. You should know that `less` is able to do searches by itself (press **q** to `quit` the help page presented, if needed) by using the key **/**. If you press:

```
/-f
```

and press enter, you will see the `-f` highlighted (presing `n` will move to the next match).

Or, if you need to see only the lines that match an string, do:

```
&-f
```

If you need to activate such searches from the command line, do:

```
$ LESS=+'/-f' man grep
```